# Second hard drive won't show up in Ubuntu 16.04.

Tags: hard-drive, live-usb

I have 3 hard drives that I bought off a friend. They aren't showing up on Ubuntu 16.04. The output of fdisk -l showed no change with and without the hard drives plugged in, and appeared to only list the partitions on my main hard drive. The hard drives didn't show up in gparted either, only my main hard drive did.

Strangely enough, when I unplugged my main hard drive, and booted into liveboot, I was successfully able to access and format all 3 hard drives without an issue. When I plugged my main hard drive back in, and tested the hard drives in Ubuntu 16.04, they didn't show up. Anyone have any ideas as to how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure they are mounted? There is an application called "Disks", which might be of some help. Try that booting up like normal, with all of your drives connected, and then poke around in the Disks application.

Comment: Um, I have no clue what happened but the drives are magically working now. Yesterday, I compared the output of fdisk -l before plugging the hdd in to the output after plugging it in. There was no difference, and I tried everything I could think of. Somehow it works now. Thanks :)